# PHP - Best Practice for Passing Variables to Include Files

Tags: php, include

This is more of a 'How *should* I?' rather than 'How *do* I?' question.

Generally, what is considered the best way to pass variables to an included file?

For example, let's say I'm using a fragment for a menu, and want one of the menu items (the current one) to have a certain class name (this is a very generic sample - not something I'm actually using):

```
<?php
$links = array(
    array('text' => 'home', 'href' => 'home.php'),
    array('text' => 'about', 'href' => 'about.php'),
    array('text' => 'contact', 'href' => 'contact.php') 
);
?>
<ul>
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) : 
    $link = $links[$i];
    $is_active = ($i == $active_index);
?>
    <li><a <?=($is_active ? 'class="active"' : '')?> href="<?=$link['href']?>"><?=$link['text']?></a></li>
<?php endfor; ?>
</ul>
```

i'll call the above 'menu.inc.php'.  obviously it's looking for a variable (int) called `$active_index` to determine which link to give the '.active' class to.

so - you could just define `$active_index` before calling the include, but this seems like poor practice to me since perhaps a variable of that name might have been defined for something else earlier and a later part of the script is still looking for it.

or - you could use an absolute path and append variables using a querystring (`include 'menu.inc.php?active_index=1'`), but again that seems like a bad idea since you might need the 'real' `$_GET` within any given `include`.

or - you could start each included file with `ob_start` and return `ob_end_clean()`, then use something like this to get the return:

```
function load_view($file, $variables){
  extract($variables);
  return include($file);
}
// passed like
<?=load_view('menu.inc.php', array('active_index' => 2))?>
```

but again this seems to have a number of cons (having to restructure all your include files accordingly with the `ob` functions and a `return` statement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like an object for this, as described [in this MVC stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833324/how-do-you-pass-values-between-php-pages-for-mvc). In a file called viewMenu.class.php,

```
class viewMenu
  {
  private $active_link;

  public function __construct ( $active_link )
    {
    $this->active_link = $active_link; 
    }
  //If the constructor doesn't work for you, try a "set" method.  

  public function view ()
    {
    $active_link = $this->active_link;
    include_once ( "menu.inc.php" );
    }
  }
```

Defining $active_link inside the view method contains the variable scope of $active_link to within the method.  Then call this code:

```
$aViewMenu = new viewMenu( $active_link );
$aViewMenu->view();
```

However, I'm nearly new to MVC in PHP, and I welcome reproach.

Comment: This is similar to the approach taken in Zend Framework views. The controller sets up the model in the view (`ViewMenu` takes on both the controller and model roles above) and then executes a view script via `include` inside the view's `render()` method. You could achieve the same effect above by dropping the `$active_link` local variable and access it in the included script using `$this->active_link`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would just define `$active_index` before including, or, being perhaps a little more inline with good coding practices, make the menu generation a function with an `$active_index` parameter.

For instance (forgive the mess that follows):

```
<?php // menu.php
$links = array(
    array('text' => 'home', 'href' => 'home.php'),
    array('text' => 'about', 'href' => 'about.php'),
    array('text' => 'contact', 'href' => 'contact.php') 
);

function generate_menu($active_index)
{
?>
    <ul>
    <?php
    $linkcount = count($links);
    for($i = 0; $i < $linkcount; $i++)
    {
        $link = $links[$i];
        $is_active = ($i == $active_index);
    ?>
        <li><a <?=($is_active ? 'class="active"' : '')?> href="<?=$link['href']?>"><?=$link['text']?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
}
```

and:

```
<?php // mypage.php
generate_menu(0);
?>
blah blah content goes here
```

Comment: thanks for the reply rfw, but as i mentioned this seems like poor practice as those variable names would be global.  also, you can use querystring with includes if using absolute paths (see example 3 here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), but for the reasons listed above i don't think this is the best general approach either (since you'd then lost the original $_GET variables)

Comment: @Big MoMo perhaps you'd like my function approach better?

Comment: the function approach has a couple drawbacks (mentioned in the original post), and requires restructuring of the 'view' files - ideally, the view files are html with very little php - just enough to supply content (smarty and codeigniter are good examples, although each of those has it's own pros and cons).  also, function like that can get a little cumbersome when dealing with large view files, and doesn't do much to separate logic from content.

Comment: @Big MoMo: If you're looking to do that, maybe you should use an MVC framework like CodeIgniter? Though, generally speaking, for things like menus, they're generated dynamically via functions...