# What does it mean to serialize data or an object?

Tags: php, codeigniter, serialization

using php, if possible.

What does it mean? I was reading one of my old questions ( [How do you pass values between PHP pages for MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833324/how-do-you-pass-values-between-php-pages-for-mvc))
and in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3833614/1002469) it says:

> The part responsible for transferring the data between the controller and the view is the View engine (or class) internal to CodeIgniter. It takes that array from the controller and deserializes it for the view.

I don't know what that means (I read the comments).  I put CodeIgniter as the example and tag, but I guess it could be a general question.

Thanks.

Comment: In your example quote, "deserialize" is used incorrectly. It should be  "serialize". That might have contributed to your confusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To serialize data is to generate a storable representation of a value as a string, for example: 
json_encode is a type of serialization but PHP has native support also of serialize that can serialize almost any type of data except resources types, you can find a small guide to serialization here:
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/The-Basics-of-Serializing-Objects-in-PHP/

For the full manual that corresponds to PHP you can find it in the link that Cédric Belin posted in the post below :D

Answer (score 10):

Serializing usually means converting object (or complex object structure) into text/binary form, suitable for storing or transmitting over network.

Deserialization is a reverse process.

Answer (score 7):

See [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Serialization is the process of converting an object or an object graph in linear sequence of bytes for storage or transmission to another location.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store your data in memory or transmit over computer network and reconstruct later in different environment, first you need to convert this data into understandable/usable format by computers which is binary format (00011010101011...).

[SERIALization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is a convertion of data structure into SERIES of bits.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  The SERIAL part was very helpful.